# How to get dynamic width of column in StackedColumn chart

Tags: aspose, aspose-slides

I’m working in a project where I need to deal with StackedColumn chart using Aspose.Slides library. For each column of the chart, there is a corresponding counter value and I need to display it like in this sample slide.

[image: Template]

Basically, each label should be displayed symmetrical to the middle of the corresponding column’s width.

[image: Correct label positioning]

With 5 columns, the labels display fine like the template. However, if there are less than that the labels will display like these.

[image: With 4 columns]
[image: With 2 columns]

Here is the piece of code that is responsible for adding data point for the series and adding label for each data point.

```
dataSeries.DataPoints.AddDataPointForBarSeries(itemValueCell);
dataSeries.Format.Fill.FillType = fillType;
dataSeries.Format.Fill.SolidFillColor.Color = fillColour;
dataSeries.ParentSeriesGroup.Overlap = 100;
dataSeries.ParentSeriesGroup.GapWidth = 75;
var counter = workbook.GetCell(index, rowIndex, 7, item.Counter);

dataSeries.DataPoints[index - 1].Label.ValueFromCell = itemNameCell;
slide.Shapes.AddAutoShape(ShapeType.Rectangle, startX + dataSeries.GapWidth / 4.0f + (index - 1) * dataSeries.GapWidth * 1.85f, startY, dataSeries.GapWidth / 2.0f, 20);
var label = ((AutoShape)slide.Shapes[slide.Shapes.Count() - 1]);
label.TextFrame.Text = counter.Value.ToString();
label.FillFormat.FillType = FillType.NoFill;
label.LineFormat.FillFormat.FillType = FillType.NoFill;
label.TextFrame.TextFrameFormat.CenterText = NullableBool.True;
label.TextFrame.TextFrameFormat.AutofitType = TextAutofitType.Normal;
label.TextFrame.Paragraphs[0].Portions[0].PortionFormat.FillFormat.FillType = FillType.Solid;
label.TextFrame.Paragraphs[0].Portions[0].PortionFormat.FillFormat.SolidFillColor.Color = Color.FromArgb(0, 173, 219);
```

I tried to get ActualWidth of each datapoint but only got zero value. It seems the field’s value will only be set once the entire chart (or maybe the entire powerpoint file) is rendered. Does anyone know how to get dynamic width value of each column from code (even before it is rendered)?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I got the answer myself. Just call this before getting actual width.

```
chart.validateChartLayout();
```